# Building breadcrumb using React Router V6.4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

After reading docs about new implementation of v6.4, I came across [this](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-matches) new `useMatches` hook.

I attempt to apply this on a project I'm currently working on and ended up with the following structure.

### Routes

```js
export const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<RootLayout />}>
      <Route index element={<TopComponent />} />

      <Route
        path="path"
        element={<TopComponent />}
        handle={{
          crumb: () => <Link to="/path">path</Link>,
        }}
      >
        <Route
          path="path"
          element={<ChildComponent />}
          handle={{
            crumb: () => <Link to="path">Path</Link>,
          }}
        >
          <Route path=":ID" element={<DynamicComponent />}/>
        </Route>
        <Route
          path="path"
          element={<ChildComponent />}
          handle={{
            crumb: () => <Link to="path">Path</Link>,
          }}
        />
      </Route>
)
```

- `TopComponent`: Main single nav item
- `ParentComponent`: Nav item with sub-routes
- `ChildComponent`: Nested Component

### Breadcrumb Component

```js
import { useMatches } from "react-router-dom";

export function Breadcrumbs() {
  let matches = useMatches();
  let crumbs = matches
    // first get rid of any matches that don't have handle and crumb
    .filter((match) => Boolean(match.handle?.crumb))
    .map((match) => match.handle.crumb(match.data));

  const breadcrumbs = crumbs.map((crumb, ind) => {
    const notLast = ind < crumbs.length - 1;
    if (notLast) {
      return (
        <>
          <span className="name">{crumb}</span>
          <span className="arrow">&gt;</span>
        </>
      );
    } else {
      return <span className="name">{crumb}</span>;
    }
  });

  return <div>{breadcrumbs}</div>;
}
```

### Result

`a` tags that enables navigating on clicking

```
ParentComponent > ChildComponent
```

### Questions

- Am I doing things right or there is a better way to construct this?
- How to make this method work with dynamic routes?

Comment: It seems you followed the [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-matches#breadcrumbs) closely enough. I suspect it is not incorrect. What is the question or concern with route params? The docs have an example.

Comment: i think i don't understand `loader - handle` cycle. So `loader` is where i can work with dynamic routes then whatever returned from `loader` is passed to `handle` as a prop/parameter then i can use it to show say a title as a breadcrumb item?

Comment: The `loader` function is called prior to the route loading and rendering the routed component. The `handle` object is accessible from the routed component once it's mounted and rendered. `handle` is just an object that you can place whatever you want it. Check the example for the `path="conversation/:id"` route, the `handle` holds a `crumb` property that is a function that takes a `data` arg (*passed from the `match` object*). The `Breadcrumbs` component passes the current `match` object to the `crumb` function. `loader` and `handle` are not really related.

Comment: thx for ur time brother, isn't this part from `conversation/:id` handle's comment  `we decided to make this one a function so we can pass the data from the loader to it so that our breadcrumb is made up of dynamic content` means there is a relation?.

Comment: Lol, maybe. The value returned from the loader is on `match.data` in the component  after it mounts and renders. *Then* the component decides to pass `match.data` to a function defined in `handle`. There's no direct relationship other than what the component is doing with the loader data and provided handle.

Comment: Ok, with this, is there an issue with code you are trying to use the relates to dynamic route path parameters, a loader function, and a route handle?

Comment: im sorry for late response. i got it ty for explaining the *relation*. I've tried implementing dynamic routes and everything is working just fine. tysm